# Insert multiple csv fields into 1 database field

Tags: php

I am uploading a csv to my database, in the csv there are 2 fields Firstname and Lastname. On my database I want to combine them into one Name column. However I am not sure exactly how to do so

```
        $compname = $data[4] . ',' . $data[5];
    $import="INSERT into gaa_ccinvoices_contacts(id,name,contact,email,contact_note) values('$data[0]','". $compname ."','". $compname ."','$data[6]','". $compname ."')";
```

Comment: DON'T do this... never denormalize your data. and as written, you're vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: What you've written should work. Are you getting an error when you try it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really wanto to insert only a composed field in the database use string concatenation :

```
 $dataComposed = $data[0] . ',' . $data[1];
 $import="INSERT into table(name) values('" . $dataComposed ."')";
```

Comment: I get what you are trying to do here, can't seem to avoid the syntax error now.

Comment: I've tried that as well, updating code above with exactly what I have

Comment: Strange, It's just a syntax error but everything seemed to upload correctly. Thanks for the help